# Node-red Google Drive API

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, node-red

I would like to use Google Drive API to list changed files / new files in a specific folder using node-red.

I would like use the following flow:
https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-google

Any advice how to create a simple flow that achieves this?

Comment: Try following the [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) as node-red is a wrapper for official Google APIs Node.js Client.